# Where does TypeScript find its variable declarations?

Tags: typescript, declaration, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

The `tsc` compiler always happily compiles `console.log("foo")`. Where is the variable `console` declared? The compiler accepts this program even with all `lib`s turned off in my `tsconfig.json`. So is `console` assumed to be universal? What other variables are always declared? More generally, how can I find out what other declarations exist, and where they are coming from? (The only debugging flag I can find is `--extendedDiagnostics`, but it seems almost useless.)

Comment: When you do Command + Click or Ctrl + Click on `console.log` in your IDE, it should take you to the file where those are declared :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TypeScript is distributed with a set of `lib.*.d.ts` declaration files which describe the standard  library APIs provided by various JavaScript runtimes.

`console` is described therein.

The language determines which of these files are applicable based on the `--target` option, automatically including them in the compilation context.

For example `"target": "es5"` will cause the compiler to include `lib.es5.d.ts` in the compilation context.

You can explicitly configure which of these built-in declaration files should be referenced using the `--lib` option.

For example `"lib": ["es2015", "dom", "dom.iterable"]`.

If you use the navigation features of your IDE, such "go to definition"  in Visual Studio Code, will navigate to the to the decoration for console, allowing you to see where it is.

Additional declaration files, such as those  provided by various `@types` packages, may also contribute potentially overlapping declarations describing JavaScript runtime APIs. This is actually good behavior because it allows packages to describe additional capabilities they provide.

For example `@types/node` contains such decorations.

When declared by 3rd party packages, the inclusion of these additional global declaration files is controlled by the  `--types` option as opposed to the `--lib` option.

For example `"types": ["node"]`.

The inclusion of these types is not impacted by the `--target` option.

Comment: Thanks - though my confusion is that even when I set `"lib": []`, the compiler still seems to know about `console`, leading me to assume that `console` is also declared somewhere else. My expectation is that when setting `"lib": []`, there should be no predeclared variables at all, but the existence of `console` violates that.

Comment: Yes. There's no restriction that other declaration files won't Define some subset of the standard Library types. This is actually good behavior because it allows packages to describe additional capabilities of their run time. For example `@types/node` contains such decorations. The global types added to the when declared by 3rd party packages are controlled by the `"types"` option instead of `"lib" `

Comment: You're right - in my case `console` was declared in `@types/node` in `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\4.0`. I don't understand what the compiler's search path is for typings - but that's a future question. Thanks!

Comment: That's actually a feature called Automatic Type Aquisition it can be disabled